# Is there a OSM tile server that allows you to style like google api?

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, google-maps-api

The google maps API allows you to style the map you get back. Is there an OSM equivalent?  This question asked how google did it [How are Google serving up their Styled Maps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28089/how-are-google-serving-up-their-styled-maps)
has there been any progress since then in the OSM community?

Comment: Something like this perhaps http://osm2vectortiles.org/maps/

Comment: thanks @user30184, I was thinking of server side styling of the raster but those vector tiles are making me think in different ways.